# Call shell vs Wscript.Shell using cmd.exe

Tags: vba, shell, cmd

I am using the following code and it is working fine.

```
path = "cd C:\Program Files\bin & AppX File.txt"

Call Shell("cmd.exe /k " & path, vbNormalFocus)
```

**However,** I have to use the waitOnreturn so I changed to the following code and **it is not working anymore.**

```
path = "cd C:\Program Files\bin & AppX File.txt"
Dim wsh As Object
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wsh.Run ("cmd.exe /k " & path & ", windowStyle, waitOnReturn")
```

The error is "  couldn't read file "File.txt,": no such file or directory  " but the file is there.
The Filename is **File.txt**.
The program's name is AppX. The program allows me to run the file using cmd.exe if I first change the direction to the AppX path. Then, to run the file using cmd.exe, I need to run "AppX File.txt"
Is there something running with the WScript.Shell code

Comment: `1` and `true` are arguments of the `run` method, not part of the command string

Comment: Thanks, I have changed them, but I still have the same error.

Comment: @MCND I think I got what you mean, I change it to wsh.Run "cmd.exe /k " & path, windowStyle, waitOnReturn . It is working now , Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

```
  wsh.Run ("cmd.exe /k " & path & ", windowStyle, waitOnReturn")
```

to

```
  wsh.Run "cmd.exe /k " & path, windowStyle, waitOnReturn
```

and it is working now

Answer (score 0):

Because the file has spaces in its name, you need to enclose the path in quotation marks. So something like:

```
path = "cd \"C:\Program Files\bin & AppX File.txt\""
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, that did not work. The file name is only File.txt. It does not have space. I have edited my question.